# Command docker start -a <Container ID> do nothing, "Ubuntu 20.04.02 LTS"

Tags: docker, ubuntu, ubuntu-20.04

i'm trying to run the `start` command in docker after creating a container.
for example :

```
$ docker create busybox echo hi there
```

it gives me the id of that container like `4e59d0fe8584bb4dcaf44dbce100253b6767bf51546edc27f29f39f52ed57957`

and when i try to start that container without any flags like: `-a` flag
it works, but it only gives me that id back again.
but when i try to show the output using the attach `-a` flag, actually nothing happened, even it didn't give me an error, simply the command still running without anything happened.

> i also couldn't kill the command and stop the execution by Ctrl+c, so the only option i had to close the terminal

[image]
i tried to make the problem clear as possible as i can

Answer (score 0):

You can run the image via this command:

```
docker run -it busybox
```

It goes you to shell environment and you have -i (interactive) -t (tty) terminal, which means you see the terminal.

Comment: oh sorry, my bad. the command was busybox not hello world, i'm gonna edit it now

Comment: That's no problem, you should do the same command. Just replace `ubuntu` with `busybox`, so that you go into `sh` shell of the busybox container.

Answer (score 0):

The default `CMD`(PID1) for `busybox image` is `sh`, see [this](https://github.com/docker-library/busybox/blob/8e007ee409b22843ba78d19e5f68518505e9ff0d/stable/uclibc/Dockerfile#L3).

For `docker create busybox echo hi there`, the `COMMAND` becomes `echo hi there`. This means after container starts, it will first execute `echo hi there`, then as PID1 exit, the container exit too. If you use `docker ps`, you won't find your container, you could just find your exited container with `docker ps -a`.

So,

- If you intend to run a one time task, then as the container finish its task, it's normal you could not enter into container anymore.
- If you intend to run a daemon task, leave the container service there, you should choose a command which won't finish after run, then your container will still there.

For your case, to quick let you understand it, you could use next to have a quick understanding, use `tail -f /dev/null` to let the container not exit:

```
# docker create busybox sh -c "echo hi there; tail -f /dev/null"
840d7c972a96712e48c9aa391aa63638fb10e12307797e338157105bdfb6934e
root@shlava:~# docker start 840d7c972a96712e48c9aa391aa63638fb10e12307797e338157105bdfb6934e
840d7c972a96712e48c9aa391aa63638fb10e12307797e338157105bdfb6934e
root@shlava:~# docker logs 0ae2d689e63a8688213d1eaf285e555ba3d672b8953f0d2730a1897c9d648a26
hi there
root@shlava:~# docker exec -it 0ae2d689e63a8688213d1eaf285e555ba3d672b8953f0d2730a1897c9d648a26 /bin/sh
/ #
```